# How can I prevent [flush-8:16] and [jbd2/sdb2-8] from causing GUI unresponsiveness?

Tags: cpu-load, disk-usage

Approximately twice a week, the entire graphical interface will lock up for about 10-20 seconds without warning while I am doing simple tasks such as browsing the web or writing a paper. When this happens, GUI elements do not respond to mouse or keyboard input, and the System Monitor applet displays 100% IOWait processor usage.

Today, I finally happened to have GNOME Terminal already open when the problem started. Despite other applications such as Google Chrome, Firefox, GNOME Do, and GNOME Panel being unresponsive, the terminal was usable. I ran `iotop` and observed that commands named `[flush-8:16]` and `[jbd2/sdb2-8]` were alternately using 99.99% IO.

What are these, and how can I prevent them from causing GUI unresponsiveness?

### Details

```
$ mount | grep ^/dev
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
/dev/sdb2 on /home type ext4 (rw,commit=0)
$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename        Type        Size     Used    Priority
/dev/sdb3       partition   1052252  0       -1
```

`/dev/sda` is an [OCZ-VERTEX2](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-vertex-2-sata-ii-2-5-ssd.html) and `/dev/sdb` is a [WD10EARS](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=120#tab3). Here is [`dumpe2fs /dev/sdb2`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/579783/) and [`smartctl /dev/sdb --all`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/580257/).

I don't see anything unusual in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I can tell you what they are: They are part of the file system - `flush` writes the RAM buffer/cache to disk, and jbd2 deals with the ext4 journal.

Comment: Is this a laptop, by the way?

Comment: Just thinking aloud here: 100% IOWait could mean that the file system is waiting for the disk to wake from a low power state - agressive power saving is a major feature of the WD Greens. But not sure why it would lock the system. There's presumably a `/dev/sda` as well - which disk holds what? Like "root on sda, home on sdb"?

Comment: Could be a bad disk, check SMART data or output of `dmesg` for disk errors.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this after performing a fresh installation of 11.04.

Comment: "too localized" -- too bad that I'm a future visitor who found this question because I'm looking at exactly the same problem.

Comment: @DXM It feels awkward, but I think the correct thing for you to do in this situation is to open a new question and just make sure to mention this one. I'm still curious about what caused this problem, but it's been two years since I lost my ability to verify proposed solutions.

Comment: After few days of digging, I think I found a good description of what was causing my hangs: http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm

Comment: @ændrük: I feel that sometimes this community tends to close questions IMHO just a bit too aggressively, but if I'm reading this page correctly, did you close your own question as too localized? If yes, that definitely will be a new one for me :)

Comment: @DXM Yes, I closed it because I can't reproduce the issue anymore and thus will never be able to mark any answer as accepted. I've gotten the impression that on some other sites closing is viewed almost as a form of punishment, but at least here it tends more to be just a way to tidy the site and keep content relevant. I do think the term "too localized" is a bit of a stretch for this situation, but it's [the closest option we have](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/322).

Comment: eh, can reopen this? This is affecting many ubuntu users and the associated bug on launchpad is still active: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/607560   my ssd is dying :(((

Answer (score 4):

I'll venture a theory:

`/dev/sdb1` is perhaps swap space?

If something central to the graphical interface has been offloaded to disk, the GUI can't continue until it has received those data. If the swap disk is sleeping, this means it's stuck until the disk responds.

I think this would give a temporary lockup, and the 10-20 second period fits the time it takes for a sleeping disk to respond. 
The terminal is presumably still responsive because all it needs is already in RAM.

Some terminal tools to explore the theory:

- `hdparm -C /dev/sdX` tells you whether a disk is sleeping:

  ```
  $ sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdb
  /dev/sdb:
  drive state is:  standby
  ```

  `active/idle` means that it's running. In state `standby` or `sleeping` it has stopped spinning and will take a while to start up again. See `man hdparm`.
- `free -m` says how much swap space is used:

  ```
  $ free -m     
               total       used       free     [...]
  Mem:          5973       4928       1045     [...]
  -/+ buffers/cache:       1091       4882
  Swap:         6234          0       6234
  ```

  "Swap:" is the relevant line, in this example 6.2 GB swap is available and nothing is used.

If this is the issue, you could either move swap to sda or disable spindowns for sdb.

Comment: This is a good theory, but I think the problem isn't related to swap. While the swap partition is indeed on the same drive, the system rarely, if ever, uses it. `free -m` during the lockup confirmed that 0 MB of swap was being used.

Comment: @ændrük Ok, then I'll have to leave the field to the experts.